# pytest -> How to use fixture return value in test method under a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, automated-tests, pytest, python-unittest

I have a fixture that returns a value like this:

```
import pytest

@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="module")
def oneTimeSetUp(browser):
    print("Running one time setUp")
    if browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        print("Running tests on FF")
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        print("Running tests on chrome")
    yield driver
    print("Running one time tearDown")
```

This fixture gets the browser value from another fixture which is reading the command line option.

Then I have a test class where I have more than one test methods and they all want to consume the same returned value driver to proceed the tests.

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetUp")
class TestClassDemo():

    def test_methodA(self):
        # I would like to use the driver value here
        # How could I do this?
        # Something like this
        self.driver.get("https://www.google.com")
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "some id")
        print("Running method A")

    def test_methodB(self):
        print("Running method B")
```

Using self.driver fails with the error message

```
self = <test_class_demo.TestClassDemo object at 0x102fb6c18>

    def test_methodA(self):
>       self.driver.get("https://www.google.com")
E           AttributeError: 'TestClassDemo' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

I am aware that I can pass the fixture as an argument to every method where I want to use that, but that is not the best way because I need this in every method and it should be possible to pass it to the class and then use it in all the test methods.

What is the best way that I can make the driver object available to the methods?

**EDIT 1:**

Created the fixture in conftest.py like this as suggested

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="class") # <-- note class scope
def oneTimeSetUp(request, browser): # <-- note the additional `request` param
    print("Running one time setUp")
    if browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        print("Running tests on FF")
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        print("Running tests on chrome")

    ## add `driver` attribute to the class under test -->
    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver
    ## <--

    yield driver
    print("Running one time tearDown")
```

I have one more class, which object in need in the TestClassDemo and I need to pass the same driver instance to the class. Consider it as class ABC

```
class ABC():

    def __init(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def enterName(self):
        # Do something with driver instance
```

Then in the TestClassDemo

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetUp", "setUp")
class TestClassDemo(unittest.TestCase):

    # I need to create an object of class ABC, so that I can use it here
    # abc = ABC(self.driver)

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
    def setup(self):
        self.abc = ABC(self.driver)
    # I tried this, but it's not working
    # This error message shows up
    # AttributeError: 'TestClassDemo' object has no attribute 'driver'

    def setup_module(self):
    self.abc = ABC(self.driver)
    # This also does not work
    # Error message ->  AttributeError: 'TestClassDemo' object has no attribute 'abc'


    def test_methodA(self):
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.abc.enterName("test")
        print("Running method A")

    def test_methodB(self):
        self.abc.enterName("test")
        print("Running method B")
```

This abc object should be usable in other test_ methods also.

**All these classes are in separate modules, I mean to say in separate .py files.**

Also please explain in the answer what is the best way to use instead of yield driver instance.

**EDIT 2:**

For this example without yield, what would be the best way to run oneTimeTearDown also? I was running the tearDown steps after the yield

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def oneTimeSetUp(request, browser):
    print("Running one time setUp")
    if browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        print("Running tests on FF")
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        print("Running tests on chrome")

    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver
```

Also I tried using UnitTest class, but when I use def setUpClass(cls), I was not able to use the objects instantiated in the test_ methods. So I couldn't not figure out how to achieve that.

I also wanted to provide command line arguments like browser from the command line and when I tried unittest, I had to write the command line argument in every class. I wanted to provide them in one place only, like a test suite. So conftest helped me here.

I had a question on stackoverflow but didn't get a response. Could you please take a look at that also?
[Python unittest passing arguments to parent test class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674801/python-unittest-passing-arguments-to-parent-test-class)

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a technique outlined in the [py.text unittest integration documentation](https://pytest.org/latest/unittest.html) that may be helpful to you ... using the built-in `request` fixture. Otherwise, I'm not aware of way to access the return value of a fixture without providing the named fixture as a method param.

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="class") # <-- note class scope
def oneTimeSetUp(request, browser): # <-- note the additional `request` param
    print("Running one time setUp")
    if browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        print("Running tests on FF")
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        print("Running tests on chrome")

    ## add `driver` attribute to the class under test -->
    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver
    ## <--

    yield driver
    print("Running one time tearDown")
```

Now you can access the `driver` as a class attribute in `TestClassDemo`, as you have in your example (i.e. `self.driver` should work).

The caveat is that your fixture must use `scope='class'`, otherwise the `request` object will not possess a `cls` attribute.

I hope that helps!

---

**UPDATE**

> I have one more class, which object in need in the TestClassDemo and I need to pass the same driver instance to the class. Consider it as class ABC

It's difficult to know without more context, but it seems to me that you can probably get away with instantiating an `ABC` object at the same time that you instantiate the `driver` ... in the `oneTimeSetUp` fixture. For example ...

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="class")
def oneTimeSetUp(request, browser):
    print("Running one time setUp")
    if browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        print("Running tests on FF")
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        print("Running tests on chrome")

    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver
        request.cls.abc = ABC(driver) # <-- here

    yield driver
    print("Running one time tearDown")
```

But if you only need the ABC instance for a test class or two, here's how you might use a fixture inside the class definition ...

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetUp", "setUp")
class TestClassDemo(unittest.TestCase):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def build_abc(self, oneTimeSetUp): # <-- note the oneTimeSetup reference here
        self.abc = ABC(self.driver)

    def test_methodA(self):
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.abc.enterName("test")
        print("Running method A")

    def test_methodB(self):
        self.abc.enterName("test")
        print("Running method B")
```

I wouldn't be particularly happy with the second example. A third option would be to have another yield_fixture, or similar, that is completely separate from `oneTimeSetUp` and returns an ABC instance with the driver already wrapped.

Which way is best for you? Not sure. You'll need to decide based on what you're working with.

It's proper to note for posterity that pytest fixtures are just sugar and a bit of magic. You are not required to use them at all, if you find them difficult. pytest is happy to execute vanilla unittest TestCases.

---

> Also please explain in the answer what is the best way to use instead of yield driver instance.

Here's what I had in mind ...

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def oneTimeSetUp(request, browser):
    print("Running one time setUp")
    if browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        print("Running tests on FF")
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        print("Running tests on chrome")

    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver
```

... notice that this doesn't return (or yield) the driver object, which means that it's no longer useful to provide this fixture as a named parameter to a function/method, which should be fine if all of your test cases are written as classes (suggested by your examples).

However, if you want to use the fixture as a named parameter, don't do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, I have couple of follow up questions.
Could you please edit your answer to explain the last line?
"If you're not planning to use the oneTimeSetUp fixture in other test functions (via named parameter, for example), then the above code can be simplified further, of course."

One important question:
If I want to initialize the an object of another class in my TestClassDemo, then where should I initialize it? I need to pass the driver to the object of another class also. Please help, your answer was awesome. I was really struggling to get this done for many days

Comment: Should have __init__() in the TestClassDemo to create the object of another class? Is it possible to provide the driver to that object from the __init__(), or can it only be used in the test method?

Comment: Hi @SunShine, I just removed the last sentence, because it was poorly constructed and not very helpful. To clarify, what I meant was if using the `request` fixture works for you, for **every** test, then you don't need to use a yield_fixture or return/yield a value.

Comment: For your second question, you can create a fixture method inside the class definition with `autouse=True` to setup another instance object to be used throughout your test class. You can also use the `scope` attribute to determine when the instance of the other object is created. (Alternatively, you can define setup methods, xunit style. As in, https://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html) If you update your question with an example using the other object, I'll update my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: See https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids for an example of using `autouse=True` inside a test class.

Comment: Hi @Marty, I have update the question with Edit, please take a look. Your help is really awesome.

Comment: Hi @Marty, I tried to use both the ways you suggested, but I am sure I am not doing correctly. They are not working. I am still trying really hard to learn pytest. I would also appreciate if you could refer me to some good tutorial. Pytest documentation is very tough for me. I tried a lot but couldn't understand much. I end up trying myself without getting any good result. A tutorial with some examples would be really helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114434/discussion-between-sun-shine-and-marty).

Comment: Hi @Marty, your answer is awesome. It really help me. I have updated the question with few more doubts and a link to another question. Please take a look when you have some time

Comment: hi @Marty, This approach still results in ```AttributeError: 'TestClassDemo' object has no attribute 'driver'``` But somehow it continues to run the test case.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply call the fixture name and save the returned value in variable.

import pytest

class TestSwaggerAPIs:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class",
                params=['test1', 'test2'])
def get_api_url(self, request):
    return request.param

def test_fixture_return(self, get_api_url):
    data = get_api_url
    print('The data from fixture is:{}'.format(data))
```

============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_file.py::TestSwaggerAPIs::test_fixture_return[test1] PASSED         [ 50%]The data from fixture is:test1

test_file.py::TestSwaggerAPIs::test_fixture_return[test2] PASSED         [100%]The data from fixture is:test2

============================== 2 passed in 0.01s ===============================