# Selenium Python PageObject

Tags: python-3.x, testing, selenium-webdriver, cross-platform, pytest

I would like to know how to pass self.driver of conftest (pytest) in another Class ?

conftest.py

```
  def driver(request):
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote("xxxxx")
  def teardown():
    self.driver.quit()
```

TestSample.py

```
Class B():
  # How use self.driver ?????
```

Answer (score 1):

you are allowed to play with fixture

conftest.py

```
  def driver(request):
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote("xxxxx")
  def teardown():
    self.driver.quit()
```

TestSample.py

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver")
Class B():
  # How use self.driver ?????
  def test_sample(self, driver):
    tuto(driver)
```

[Link explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760366/pytest-how-to-use-fixture-return-value-in-test-method-under-a-class)

Answer (score -2):

Inherit b() class with a() and then use super() to access the self.driver of super class a()

Comment: sorry i just modify the context