# How to separate tests and fixtures

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have example project in PyCharm - consist of a simple test that checking sign-in to the given correct Slack workspace. It has `web_drivers` directory with `chromedriver` inside, `conftest.py` with webdriver setup for test and `tests.py` with actual test, f.e.

> conftest.py

```
import os
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def driver_get(request):
    web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join("web_drivers","chromedriver.exe"))
    yield web_driver

def fin():
    web_driver.close()

request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

> tests.py

```
import pytest

class TestSlackWorkspace(object):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self, driver_get):
        self.driver = driver_get
        self.driver.get("https://slack.com/signin")
        self.input_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//input[@type='text' and @id='domain']")
        self.continue_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//button[@id='submit_team_domain']")

    def test_correct_workspace(self):
        self.input_field.send_keys("test")
        self.continue_button.click()
        assert self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@id='signin_header']"
        ).is_displayed(), "Login page should be displayed"
```

Now the question is to divide test to the page initialization part - `def setup`, and actual test execution part - `def test_correct_workspace` to the different classes and files(something like Page Object Pattern)

So base of `conftest.py` should be the same, and divide `test.py` to i.e.

> page.py

```
class SlackWorkspace(object):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def __init__(self, driver_get):
        self.driver = driver_get
        self.driver.get("https://slack.com/signin")
        self.input_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text' and @id='domain']")
        self.continue_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='submit_team_domain']")
```

> test.py

```
class TestWorkspace(object):
    def test_correct_workspace(self):
        self.input_field.send_keys("test")
        self.continue_button.click()
        login_page = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@id='signin_header']")
        assert login_page.is_displayed(), "Login page should be displayed"
```

But for sure it will not work in that form:

1) Somehow `driver_get` should be imported to page initialization file and forwarder to `__init__` - ?

2) Somehow page initialization should be linked with test realization in other files-?

Have no idea how to organize all these imports between separate files

Answer (score 2):

In Page Object pattern, direct reference to driver should be avoided in the test classes. You can have page.py as a base class to have common methods. The set up can be moved to a different page e.g. login.py. This set up method should return the page you are trying to verify. Test methods should then use these page objects for verification. I keep login as a fixture in conftest.py then use it across tests & other fixtures. For example, here's my attempt to give you an overview. You should read more on [page object pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html).

I recommend using [pytest-selenium](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-selenium) plugin which reduces a lot of boilerplate code with using selenium with pytest

```
conftest.py

@fixture
def selenium(): 
     # pytest-selenium provides this fixture & you can override it if required.
    return selenium

@fixture
def home(selenium):
    #do login
    return HomePage
```

---

```
login.py

from page import Page #Import base class with common methods.

class LoginPage(Page):

def login(self, driver):
    #do the login steps
    return HomePage   #return Landing Page
```

---

```
test_login.py

def test_login_successful(home):  #Use the home fixture
     assert home.is_displayed("xyz")
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find solution for this with help of [pytest -> How to use fixture return value in test method under a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760366/) and some explanation from more expirienced person in the following way

1) Turns out that fixture in conftest needs to pass initialized webdriver for my signin page from `pages.py` and initialize this page class with this driver using built-in `request` fixture. So correct `conftest.py` will looks like:

```
import pytest
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from pages import SigninPage

@pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
def driver_get(request):
    request.cls.webdriver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=os.path.join("web_drivers", "geckodriver"))
    request.cls.signin = SigninPage(request.cls.webdriver)
    yield request.cls.webdriver

    def fin():
        request.cls.webdriver.quit()
    request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

2) 'pages.py' include init of `SigninPage` with received webdriver, input field to enter workspace and button to continue, method `enter_workspace` that actually does it and return `LogInPage` with `login_page` field to be checked, so it looks like:

```
class SigninPage(object):
    def __init__(self, web_driver):
        self.driver = web_driver
        self.driver.get("https://slack.com/signin")

        self.input_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text' and @id='domain']")
        self.continue_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='submit_team_domain']")

    def enter_workspace(self):
        self.input_field.send_keys("test")
        self.continue_button.click()
        return LogInPage(self.driver)


class LogInPage(object):
    def __init__(self, web_driver):
       self.driver = web_driver
       self.login_page = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@id='signin_header']")
```

3) And finnaly, `test.py` consist of 2 things - entering workspace by calling method `enter_workspace` from `SigninPage`, which opens `LogInPage`, and then checking if login actually displayed:

```
class TestSlackWorkspace(object):
    def test_workspace(self):
        login = self.signin.enter_workspace()
        assert login.login_page.is_displayed(), "Missing!"
```

It still need to be smproved, but asked problem is solved. Thank you.